# Help Completing a First Order Separable differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=(ty)^2
$$

I am new at this so I just wanted to show my attempt for solving this and see if you guys can tell me where I went wrong?

$$
dy/dt=t^2 y^2
$$ 
then 
$$
t^2 dt=1/y^2 dy
$$ 
then 
$$
t^3/3=3/y^3+c
$$ 
then I went about solving for $y$ but I don't think my answer is correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake integrating the $1/y^2$ term. Remember that $\int 1/x^2 \, dx = -1/x $ plus an additive constant of integration. So we'd get:

$$ t^3/3 = -1/y + C $$

I guess you can take it from here.

Cheers!